# project.xcodeproj is missing, but workspace is available and works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I don't know how, but somehow I'm left with a Xcode workspace named "project", and the actual project .xcodeproj is missing. Here's what my project looks like:

```
ms2:TM jude$ tree | grep -v png | grep -v json | grep -v .h | grep -v .m
.
├── Discover
│   ├── Podfile
│   ├── Pods
│   │   ├── Headers
│   │   ├── Local\ Podspecs
│   │   └── Target\ Support\ Files
│   ├── project.pbxproj
│   ├── project.xcworkspace
│   │   ├── contents.xcworkspacedata
│   │   └── xcuserdata
│   │       └── jude.xcuserdatad
│   │           ├── UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
│   │           ├── WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
│   │           └── xcdebugger
│   │               └── Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
│   └── xcuserdata
│       └── jude.xcuserdatad
├── Resources
│   ├── discover-no-background.xcf
│   └── discover.xcf
│   ├── Info.plist
│   └── MainInterface.storyboard
├── TM
│   ├── Base.lproj
│   │   └── Main.storyboard
│   │   ├── AppIcon.appiconset
│   ├── Info.plist
└── TMTests
    ├── Info.plist

26 directories, 85 files
ms2:TM jude$
```

Any hints on how to generate it/get it back? I need the .xcodeproj for cocoapods to work, otherwise it dies with:

```
!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

    xcodeproj 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
```

Comment: Just restore it from your source code repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory itself was the xcodeproj, except that somehow I had managed to remove this extension earlier.

Answer (score 0):

remove 'master' install and update again

```
   pod repo remove master
   pod setup
   pod update
```